# Pointer on method

Tags: c++, class, pointers, methods

In my class, I try to take a pointer to a method. In my case there are some methods with similar signatures. They are public methods.

The pointer is called Metric.

The compiler reports errors on a marked line:

> D:\Job\Acronis\TestProblem\EmulationOfDisk\Emulate\CTesting.cpp:5:
>   ошибка: cannot convert 'std::vector (CTesting::)()' to 'std::vector
>   ()()' in assignment this->Metric = &this->ExTimeofWork;

I think it is a problem with the namespace. I tried to point to "CTesting::" near with a calling method. I could not fix this bug.

If I do the same construction out of class, it works.

Please, can you explain, why does this bug arise? How do I fix it?

```
class CTesting
{
    private:
        //code      
        vector<double> ( *Metric)();

    public:


        vector<double> ExTimeofWork();
        vector<double> ExTimeGenerationToAccept();
        vector<double> ExTimePoolToAccept();
        vector<double> ExMaxTimeGenerationToAccept();
        vector<double> ExMaxTimePoolToAccept();

        vector<double> GetTimeGenerationToAccept();
        vector<double> GetTimePoolToAccept();
        vector<double> GetTimeofWork();
};

void CTesting::Execute()
{
    this->Metric = &this->ExTimeofWork;//Ошибка!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    //... Code

    //...
    return;
}
```

Comment: Should be `this->Metric = &CTesting::ExTimeofWork;`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ should be the answer

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ D:\Job\Acronis\TestProblem\EmulationOfDisk\Emulate\CTesting.cpp:5: ошибка: undefined reference to `CTesting::ExTimeofWork()'

Comment: @hedgehogues Well, you need to provide a definition for that function, see [here please](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare `Metric` as pointer to member function:

```
class CTesting
{
    private:
        //code      
        vector<double> ( CTesting::*Metric)();

    public:
        vector<double> ExTimeofWork();
        void Execute();
};

void CTesting::Execute()
{
    this->Metric = &CTesting::ExTimeofWork;//Ошибка!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    //... Code

    //...
    return;
}
```

Comment: I have a problem:  ошибка: undefined reference to `CTesting::ExTimeofWork()'

Answer (score 0):

Also try just:
this->Metric = &ExTimeofWork;